# What benefits does Spring AMQP have over Spring Cloud Stream for Microservices Architecture

Tags: spring-amqp, spring-cloud-stream

I use Spring Cloud approach for building few microservices which supposed to interact with each other. For messaging between microservices I intended to use RabbitMQ and Spring AMQP, but after I looked at Spring Cloud Stream I feel lost. In my mind Spring Cloud Stream is next level of abstraction (probably too strong, but you should get overall impression) with many very useful features. So I wonder why would someone use Spring AMQP for new development? Could you please provide any Spring AMQP benefits over Spring Cloud Stream for pretty basic case when one microservice sends message to another microservice and receives reply?

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Spring Cloud Stream provides an opinionated configuration model that connects to the external system (Binder, Consumer Group etc.,). This is mainly intended for `Streaming` applications where the applications are connected via pipeline. The applications that don't fit this opinionated model can be configured directly from Spring Integration (+ Spring AMQP).

For instance, Spring Cloud Stream doesn't provide direct support for `request/reply` scenarios for example. You can read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35834089/spring-cloud-stream-request-reply-messaging-pattern) SO question and the github issue [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/815)

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's much more clear now. Basically I could use Spring Cloud Stream but I would have to implement request/reply logic myself while Spring Integration (+ Spring AMQP) does this out of box.